# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: java

I am new to Java Applet and Java Swing. Already checked similar questions but didnt help much. Exception is being thrown instead of executing the try block , once the login button is clicked. Everything else is working fine.

```
  public class signin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  Connection conn;

OracleResultSet rs = null; 
OraclePreparedStatement pst;


private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
 signin s = new signin();
 s.setVisible(true);
}
```

When clicking the login button exception is thrown instead of going to a new frame, menu.

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      


    try{

    String pass = passTF.getText().trim();
    String user = userTF.getText().trim();
    String sql = "select uname,pass from login where uname = '"+user+"' pass   
   = '"+pass+"'"; //here is the issue

   pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println("Error");
   int count = 0;
```

Rest of the try block

```
   while (rs.next())
   {
       count++;

   }
    if(count == 1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found");
        System.out.println("Success");
        menu m = new menu();
          m.setVisible(true);
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Success but no user");
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Such user does not exist!");
    }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
          System.out.println("Fail");
    }

}                                     

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new signin().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are missing the "AND" before the pass field. Also, since you are using prepared statements, use them properly (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid select statement, this code:

```
"select uname,pass from login where uname = '"+user+"' pass= '"+pass+"'"
```

Should have been like this:

```
"select uname,pass from login where uname = '"+user+"' and pass= '"+pass+"'"
```

Note that you were missing `and` in the `where` clause.

Also you should avoid these type of queries instead use `PreparedStatement` currently your code is vulnerable to sql injection attack.